# How to disable [Pre|Auto]-Merge in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, merge

I'm working in a Project with a quick changing **main** branch. for my feature integration i desided to create a new branch. Now i want to merge main with the **feature** branch and running into problems with mercurials automerge (with works fine most times).

```
others        /-0--0--0-\
main -----+---+------0--+-0-0-0-0-0---------+---
feature   \-0-0-0----------0-0-0----0-0-0---/ <-- troublemaker
```

Is there a way do the whole merging manual? I know that, when automerge have problems, it call the eclipse merge perspective which i find really confortable. Can i force mercurial to call this directly?

--Edit---

I'm ended up with merge in turtoisehg. But still, every advice or solution is welcome ;)